# Getting the order of elements in array without sorting it

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I would like to have the same functionality as sort (eg passing a comparative function), without sorting the array, but rather call for each object a function that takes as an argument the order of that particular element.

You could then use it this way:

```
var users=[
    {name:"Stephen",age:12},
    {name:"Mike",age:17},
    {name:"Jeffrey",age:32},
    {name:"Anna",age:15}
]

var result=users.getOrder(
     function(userA,userB)
            {return userA.age-userB.age>0;},
     function(user,order)
            {user.num=order;});

/* result=[
    {name:"Stephen",age:12,num:4},
    {name:"Mike",age:17,num:2},
    {name:"Jeffrey",age:32,num:1},
    {name:"Anna",age:15,num:3}
]*/
```

I would be happy if they was a way to write this using the usual Array functions or if I will have to write the loops and sort algorithm on my own. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is for example:
You can clone the original array and sort that using standard sort. Then you can loop through the cloned and see what the index of sorted is where their name or age matches.

```
for(var j =0; j<b.length;j++){
    for(var k=0;k<a.length;k++){
        if(b[j].name === a[k].name){
            b[j].num = k;
        }
    }
}
```

See fiddle with bubblesort:
http://jsfiddle.net/GeJ6v/

Comment: Ok, the only problem with that is that the mapping is O(n^2), which is not that great ... Cloning is also a bit time consuming I guess. By the way why did'nt you use standard sort in your fiddle ?

Comment: True, it can get a bit heavy on bigger datasets. Fir sorting I just happened to have the code in front of me at the exact moment so I modified that, there is not really a deeper reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution that is `O(n * sqrt(n))`:

```
Array.prototype.getOrder=function(compareFunction,indexFunction,setFunction) {
    var index={};
    this.forEach(function(user) {
        index[indexFunction(user)]=user;
    });
  
    newUsers= this.slice().sort(compareFunction);
        
    newUsers.forEach(function(user,num) {
        setFunction(index[indexFunction(user)],num);
    });
    return this;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gFLys/